# Is the table rowspan > 1 stopping its child div height setting to 100% of parent properly?

Tags: html, css

Having a bit of an issue with dynamically created table cells, possibly to do with rowspan.

```css
td{
    height:40px;
    position:relative;
}
.CoolButton{
    position:absolute;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
.CoolButtonInner{
    background-color: pink;
    height:inherit;
}
```

```html
<td rowspan="4">
    <a class="CoolButton" href="">
        <div class="CoolButtonInner">Blah Blah</div>
    </a>
</td>
```

I'm trying to get the `div` to stretch out for the HEIGHT of the entire `td` cell.

This snippet works on this site so without posting the entire codebase, what could be stopping the height from stretching down?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a width of 100% for .CoolButton Class.

```css
td{
    height:40px;
    position:relative;
}
.CoolButton{
    position:absolute;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%; ###

}
.CoolButtonInner{
    background-color: pink;
    height:inherit;
}
```

```html
<td rowspan="4">
    <a class="CoolButton" href="">
        <div class="CoolButtonInner">Blah Blah</div>
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Sorry, I was after the HEIGHT stretching. I had put that in the question title but not in the body.

Comment: Just realised the code snippets on this page are WORKING so it's my code in total that's not :(